# R: error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath)... while attempting to install SVD package on Microsoft R cloud environment

Tags: r, unix

[image: Error while installing Package Rssa which is dependent on SVD; It is showing error at the time of SVD installation as can be see below]

I am new to this community but have been using a lot of help from forums. As you might know, there are lots of threads titled "error in dyn.load", but while I try some of those, it is important to me to know if someone had faced similar issue while trying to install Rssa package or SVD package in Microsoft R open environment??

I have asked Microsoft guys as well but there seems to be little to no response. 
There were some recommendations about installing Rcpp directly from source as well, but given that Microsoft R open has preinstalled Rcpp, would it help?

Some Restrictions:
I have windows laptop not unix, so I can't test unix based solution immediately.
The error was received while attempting to install package in cloud environment of Azure using Microsoft R Server.

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Click on the "blue text" to see the error message generated. I can not paste Picture in Body text as I Need to accumulate some Reputation Points to do that.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text; post text.